# Regression Options With Categorical X values and continuous data

Tags: regression, self-study, modeling, descriptive-statistics, continuous-data

I am visualizing average biological parameters (i.e., weights, lengths, age, condition, etc.) over time (specifically across years) using geom_boxplot in ggplot in R. I have also fit a trend line through each data set using a linear model (specifically using + geom_smooth(method = "lm") and a spline using stat_smooth.An example figure is shown below:

[image: time series shown as box plots]

In most cases there appears to be an increasing trend in the mean for each parameter through time. What I would like to do is test this statistically but am not sure how to do this with categorical x variable data (year in this case). Essentially I am looking for options to run a regression type analysis to test if there has been an significant increase through time but I don't have two continuous variables.

Comment: You can consider year as a numeric variable in order to make a linear regression. Although year has discrete values, it makes sense a value between two of them.

Comment: please spell out details about samples which form the basis for averages of various parameters. It is difficult to see reasoning for using time (year) as an independent variable. age could be relevant for weight . You could do regression with the help of two continous variablle. But it depends on objective of your study.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have average length, weight, age and condition of commercially exploited Arctic char. I am (1) looking to see if these average are different from year to year (which they are base on a linear model  (lm) ANOVA) and (2) whether there is an increasing trend through time which might be the result of harvest (although we will still look into potential environmental factors).I am just unfamiliar with time-series analyses and how to test whether the slope of that regression line is increasing or decreasing statistically (given x is categorical and y is continuous).

Comment: You can do time-series analysis based on Index Nos. Further you can plot regression estimates Y based on X and check trend if any with reference to time.

Answer (score 1):

In that Fork Length plot there's a slight suggestion of a cyclical pattern as well as the possible upward trend. It may be useful to explore each of your variables as a time series using some sort of autoregression. That technique allows for the possibility that each year is dependent on one or more previous years in some way.

If you want to try this, there is a handy R function named embed() which lets you create "lagged" values at each point in a time series. For instance if you thought there was a plausible mechanism for cycles of maybe 7 or 8 years in length you could use embed(fork_length,8) to create 8 lagged values at each time point.

The idea is, you'd get a version of your dataset where you can use not just "Year" as a predictor variable but previous year, the year before that and so forth.

But absent any actual autoregressive structure it's simple to just use Year as a numeric predictor and the slope for that Year effect can be interpreted as the increase in units of the characteristic per year.

If you do try an autoregression model and find cyclical patterns in some of your fish characteristics let us know, that would be pretty cool!

P.S. Perhaps I misapprehended your question and made things too complicated. If you wanted to know how to convert a Year variable that is discrete categories (an R factor variable for instance) into a continuous one you'd do something like this:

time <- as.numeric(as.character(Year))

where "time" is the new numeric variable and "Year" is the factor variable you're currently using.